# Control [...] of type [...] must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server - but already is

Tags: asp.net

ASP.Net says that `asp:Button` needs to be inside a `<form runat="server"`. It already is inside a form. Why does it still wrong?

---

> Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Case</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="ph"/>
        <form runat="server">
            <asp:Button runat="server" text="FOOBAR"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ph.Controls.Add(new Button());
    }
}
```

---

### Error message:

> Control 'ctl02' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

### Stack trace:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Control 'ctl02' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.]
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) +9745742
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) +62
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer) +20
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +20
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +128
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +12
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +128
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +66
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
>      System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5827

Comment: You're adding the button programatically to the Placeholder tag, but not inside the form tag.  I.e., both the form and the button you add are going to be children of the placeholder tag and siblings of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks (based on your posted code) that the error is resulting from adding another button in the `Page_Load` method.   Your adding it to the Controls collection of the placeholder `ph`, which is *not inside* a `form` tag.

Try placing the `Placeholder` tag inside the `form` tag:

```
<body>
  <form ID="frm1" runat="server">
    <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="ph" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" text="FOOBAR" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Are you adding your buttons to the Page afterwards? Also, if you do
>   not specify an ID to your buttons, they will be given one
>   automatically in the form of ctl02

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Case</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="ph"/>
        <form ID="frm1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="bt1" runat="server" text="FOOBAR"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, but helps with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a webUsercontrol with .ascx file extension, and you created a webform with a .aspx extension where you want to use it t test or run your .ascx module online. Make sure you place the .ascx file inside the horizontal box by dragging the .acsx module from your solution explorer into the .aspx Design page. The horizontal box creates a default form for you. Now run the .aspx file, assuming you already set it as the start page.

Thank you.